# Backpressed Exit Dialog Box on Navigation Drawer BackPressed Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to implement the Dialog box on Back-pressed Dialog Box on Navigation Drawer Back-pressed.
The Dialog Box Have Two Buttons and When I click on Ok It Exit The Application.
The Problem is the Dialog Box is not showing...

Here is my code of Navigation Drawer onBackpressed....

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Toast.makeText(this, "BACK PRESSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose Option");
        builder.setMessage("Are You Sure To Exit??");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //go to update activity
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //go to Remove Item
                finishAffinity();
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Remove the `super.onBackPressed();` call at the beginning of the `else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application?");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(1);
                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Working on It to get a solution

Comment: Got A Solution after applying your answer... Thanks

Comment: welcome and if you have any query regarding this code just tell me.

Comment: But A little problem here, As I reopen the application the previous activity of navigation drawer will open...

Comment: on back pressed you closed the drawer first then popup an exit dialouge

Comment: Ok Let me try this out

Comment: But Can I do this?? Can You Please Tell me...!!

Comment: Remove this code
moveTaskToBack(true);
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(1);

and write Mainactivitty.this.finish;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192309/discussion-between-aalia-ali-and-mayur-panchal).